# Getting the mean value of each row for the final column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgsexpression, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean/average of all the values in a row to obtain the final value i.e., `"IRAT"`. How can I calculate it automatically using a field calculator in QGIS?

for e.g., for `SW1` I need `SL_class+....+....HI_classHI_class / 8 = IRAT`

[image]

Comment: Did you try your expression? It seems to be the answer here.

Comment: I am not getting the expression to try for multiple fields?

Comment: Your expression looks good. Something like `( field_name_1 + field_name_2 + field_name_3) / 3`. You don't need to write the `=` symbol. See [the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#using-the-field-calculator) for a usage example.

Comment: I tried and it worked, but some of the rows in the field is having NULL values because of no values for the cell so the result returns 'NULL' in IRAT , how can I fix that? Thank you

Comment: You can use the [Coalesce function](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=coalesce#coalesce), this way: `coalesce("my_field_name_1", 0)` which will become 0 if it finds a NULL value in `my_field_name_1`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. You can write the final expression as an answer below and later accept it to properly close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use array-functions with QGIS expressions to treat `NULL` (empty) values as 0 (zero). Since QGIS 3.18, there are new [aggregate functions for arrays](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays), so that it's easy to calclulate a sum or a mean.

**Add fields manually**

This expression calculates the sum of the four numbers from `value_1` to `value_4`:

```
array_sum( array( "value_1", "value_2","value_3","value_4"))
```

Same with `array_mean()` to calculate the mean for this four numbers.

**Add all fields automatically**

To get the values of **all** fields in an array, use `map_avals( attributes( ))`. Than combine it with the solution above.

If do not want all, but most fields, removing just a few fields from the calculation, first get a list of all field-names and than remove the field-names you dont want to include:

1. To get an array of all fieldnames, use: `map_akeys(attributes( ))`
2. To remove some field-names, the expression is a bit longer. In line 10 to 13 you find the four fieldnames that should not be considered. Adapt this to your needs, the rest of the expression does not need any adaption:

```
    array_sum (
        eval (
            'array('  || 
            replace (
                '"' || 
                array_to_string (
                    array_filter (
                        map_akeys( attributes( )), 
                        @element not in (
                            'fid', 
                            'OBJECTID',
                            'SUB_basin',
                            'SWno'
                        )
                    )
                ) || 
                '"', 
                ',',
                '","'
            )  || ')'
        )
    )
```

*Screenshot: based on your screenshot, I calculated a new field IRAT_value with the expression from above. It calculates the sum of all fields **except** the first four fields (the ones named `fid`, `OBJECTID`, `SUB_basin` and `SWno`), thus it creates the sum from `SL_Class` to `HI_ClassHI_Class`, where `NULL` is treated as zero (0). So for the first row: 3 + [0] + 3 + 1 + + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 = 30:*

[image]